# Command pattern to update singleton state manager

Tags: design-patterns

I am developing a SOAP server which receives data from many different asynchronous sources (CORBA), updates its internal state and pushes data to its clients.

I have a `StateManager` class which is a Singleton and that encapsulates the server state. I am wondering if it is a good idea to use Command pattern to isolate action logic decoupling `StateMananger` and `DataReceiver`.

My doubt is: am I overcomplicating my code? Seen that the state manager is a singleton, shouldn't I prefer creating updates method inside it (avoiding all command classes)?